# why giveing extra element when use for...in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I am totally confused about for...in loop in javascript. I iterate an nodeList. but it giving me some extra element why

**In HTML**

```
<div class="mm">
    klsjdfljsdf
</div>

<div class="mm">
    klsjdfljsdf
</div>
```

**In JS**

```
var mm = document.querySelectorAll(".mm");
for(var i in mm){
    alert(i);
}
```

see this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/AtxPb4IoTpdnSYDk6jc1?p=preview

Comment: what "extra element" do you mean?

Comment: you just see above link